# Horizon / Rethinkdb slow to start up on osx

Tags: macos, rethinkdb, horizon

I am currently working on a project using rethinkdb, horizon.io and angular 2.

When developing locally on my MacBook however, horizon is so slow to start up.

After running `hz serve --dev` in the terminal, it is between 2 and 3 moments before I get the callback to say horizon is ready to accept commands.

I have tried this on a windows machine and have no problems, also a colleague tried on their Mac and did not have the same issue.

Any ideas?